# Problema básico con bucles en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas tengo un problema a la hora de realizar un ejercicio básico en el cual hay que escribir en primer lugar el numero de palabras que se van a escribir en el programa, después de esto hay que escribir el numero de palabras que se hayan indicado y después imprimir los caracteres pares e impares de estas palabras. El problema que no consigo solucionar es que el programa me deje meeter tantas palabras como le indique en un primer lugar.Dejo a continuación el código para que se vea mas fácil el problema.

```
x=input()#cantidad de palabras que voy a meter para analizar

for i in x:
    b=input()#palabra que voy a analizar
    c=input()#palabra que voy a analizar
    d=b[0::2]
    e=b[1::2]
    print(d, end=" ")
    print(e)
    f=c[0::2]
    g=c[1::2]
    print(f, end=" ")
    print(g)
```

La cuestión es que quiero crear un programa en el que se indique en primer lugar el numero de palabras a analizar, después se escriba las palabras que se quieran analizar y concuerden la cantidad de estas con el numero anteriormente escrito y por ultimo me indique las letras que se encuentren en las posiciones pares y por otro lado las impares.

Comment: Prueba con `for i in range(x)`

Comment: creo fundamental empezar editando la pregunta para poner un poco de orden: qué tienes, qué quieres, qué falla. Sugiero leer [ask] y proporcionar un [example]

Comment: @CandidMoe 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Oh, si. `x = input()` deja un string. Tiene que convertirlo explicitamente a entero. Usa `x = int(input())`

Answer (score 0):

ya he conseguido resolver el problema, gracias por la ayuda. El codigo quedaria de la siguiente forma por si a alguien le sirve:

```
   x=int(input())


for i in range(x):
    b=input()
    d=b[0::2]
    e=b[1::2]
    print(d, end=" ")
    print(e)
```